# iOS Swift: Pushing a View Onto the Stack From Within a Custom Tableview Cell

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift3

I have a tableview inside a VC that has a navigation controller and it contains custom table cells. I was wondering what the best practice is for pushing onto the parent VC's navigation stack if a button in the custom table cell is tapped. I am able to get this to work if i pass the parent VC's navigation controller to the cell; but is this the most effective/efficient practice? Please see my current implementation below:

**UserAccountVC:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell:TextPostTableViewCell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TextPostTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! TextPostTableViewCell

        cell.setupCell(navigationController: self.navigationController!)

        cell.selectionStyle = .none

        return cell
}
```

**CustomTableCell:**

```
import UIKit

class TextPostTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var aNavigationController: UINavigationController!

    //MARK: Actions
    @IBAction func profilePicButtonTapped() { //We want to present a users profile

        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "SuccessfulLogin", bundle: nil)
        let cc = (sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "otherUserViewController")) as!  OtherUserAccountViewController
        self.aNavigationController.pushViewController(cc, animated: true)
    }

    func setupCell(navigationController: UINavigationController) -> Void {

        aNavigationController = navigationController
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not best practice.  You can setup an `IBAction` in interface builder for your `UIButton` or add your `UIViewController` as a target in `cellForRowAt`.  With either method you may need some method of identifying the indexPath, since you are not using `didSelectRow` in your tableview delegate:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell:TextPostTableViewCell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TextPostTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! TextPostTableViewCell
    cell.button.tag = indexPath.row // Or use some other method of identifying your data in `myAction(_:)`
    cell.button.addTarget(self, action:, @selector(myAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use delegate in this situation.
The code is a bit more here, but this is better way in iOS development IMO.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell:TextPostTableViewCell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TextPostTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as!     TextPostTableViewCell

        cell.delegate = self

        cell.selectionStyle = .none

        return cell
    }
}

extension ViewController: TextPostTableViewCellDelegate {
    func didTappedProfilePicButton() {
        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "SuccessfulLogin", bundle: nil)
        let cc = (sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "otherUserViewController")) as!  OtherUserAccountViewController
        navigationController?.pushViewController(cc, animated: true)
    }
}

protocol TextPostTableViewCellDelegate: class {
    func didTappedProfilePicButton()
}

class TextPostTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    weak var delegate: TextPostTableViewCellDelegate?

    //MARK: Actions
    @IBAction func profilePicButtonTapped() { //We want to present a users profile
        delegate?.didTappedProfilePicButton()
    }

}
```